# how to find a NodeData  in tree of Nodes?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a Node structure as below,this Node has stringdata and list of nodes as it's children. I wanted to search a data in this tree
I wrote a recursive function FindNode(Node intree,string target)

```
public class Node
{
   public string Data;
   public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
   //some code
   public Node(string r)
   {
        this.Data = r;
   }

   public string getData()
   {
          return this.Data;
   }

   //some code
   public List<Node> getchildren()
   {
         return this.Children;
    }
       //some code
}
```

target is the string which I want to find and the intree is the begining of the tree(ROOT) 
I have problem after while loop what should I return after that?
If I am wrong how should I write it?

```
public Node FindNode(Node intree,string target)
{
    if(intree.getData()==target)
          return intree;
    else 
    {
         while(intree.getchildren()!=null) 
         {
             foreach(Node n in intree.getchildren())
              {
                   FindNode(n,target);
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work here? It's already good.

Comment: after while I have error not all paths return a Node

Comment: @NeginNicki You have an initializer on your Children property and as a result it will never be null (unless of course you set it to null in some code not posted). As a result you open yourself to an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right,also I didn't set the children null in my codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
public Node FindNode(Node intree,string target)
{
    if(intree.getData()==target)
          return intree;
    else 
    {

              foreach(Node n in intree.getchildren())
              {                
                  Node node = FindNode(n,target) ; //CHECK FOR RETURN 

                  if(node != null) 
                      return node;            

              }

     }

     return null;
}
```

The difference is that I checked for return of `FindNode` method, and if it's not `null`, return result.

Just note that in case of dupplicated nodes in the tree (nodes with the same string) it will return *first* occuarance.

Comment: what will happen if intree.getchildren is null is it correct?this will not give an exception?

Comment: @NeginNicki: it can not be null, by class definition I see in code provided.

Comment: suppose after going through intree will be a leaf what it will do?

Comment: @NeginNicki: sorry, didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: after time the function is going down the tree so it will reach a place where the node hasn't any children so there isn't any Node in the list for going to foreach

Comment: @NeginNicki: ah, you have foreach which will not be executed , cause the last leaf has not any children. Not a problem.

Comment: wouldn't it better to have an if statement befor foreach so that checking the Node has list of Nodes or Not?

Comment: @NeginNicki: doesn't make any difference, may be *a little bit* in terms of performance, but it would be really a microoptimization, that *may* have an impact on very heavy calculations, but reapeat it's really micro stuff, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: @NeginNicki: do not just trust, but put it into your code, run it and *measure*. After if it's not ok, feel free to choose any other answer like accepted. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to return null and apply check where you are calling this method that if null is returned then it means no node found. Code is as follow

```
    public static Node FindNode(Node intree, string target)
    {
        if (intree.getData() == target)
            return intree;

        foreach (Node node in intree.getchildren())
        {
            Node toReturn = FindNode(node, target);
            if (toReturn != null) return toReturn;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: why this.FindNode if you are using this.FindNode then I think just the input target is fine enough

Comment: @NeginNicki yes you can remove this. also you can make this method static in this case

Comment: @NeginNicki what is diffrence in Tigran's answer and mine answer.

Comment: this.findNode is not right here because when you are using this in another places you didn't so the place is same always

Comment: @NeginNicki i have removed this. But i also thinks the method should be static.

Comment: +1 for You,waqar yes you were the first one but with a this inserted there and insisting that there isn't any difference I am in doubt now that there is a difference or not but I think 90% that this will make trouble

Answer (score 2):

Given that there could be more than one match in the tree you would be better off returning an `IEnumerable<Node>`.  Also you don't need to put those odd `get` methods in there.  And finally did you mean to only search leaf nodes or did you want to search all nodes (the else statement)?

```
public IEnumerable<Node> FindNode(Node intree,string target)
{
    if(intree.Data ==target)
        yield return intree;

    foreach (var node in intree.Children.SelectMany(c => FindNode(c, target))
        yield return node;
}
```

If you want the first matching node, just call `First()` on the result.  If you want to make sure there is only one, call `Single()` on it.

Comment: I wanted to search the whole tree but if in the between of searching it finds a first Node then finishing it.so it has better speed.I just need a match.not many matches

Comment: But that's what `.First()` will do for you.  LINQ is lazy, it will search until it finds one and then stops.  BUT this is a better API because if you later decide you need an API to find all or you need to ensure there is only 1 then it handles that.

Comment: @hsunain - NO, it goes to all levels, the SelectMany includes recursion into FindNode.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public Node FindNodeRecursively(Node parentNode, string keyword)
        {
            if(parentNode.getData() == keyword)
            {
                return parentNode;
            }
            else
            {
                if(parentNode.Children != null)
                {
                    foreach(var node in parentNode.Children)
                    {
                        var temp = FindNodeRecursively(node, keyword);
                        if(temp != null)
                            return temp;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes this if statement is better than my while statement Thanks

Comment: would you please tell me the reason of if in your foreach? why you didn't simply call the Find?

Comment: You need to actually return from the method at some point. A method call into Find() that eventually returns will not cause the calling method to return the result of that find.